# XSLT duplicate parent element for each occurrence of a child node, but with only its following siblings

Tags: xslt

My input XML is

```
<DataArea>
  <ReceiveDelivery>
      <ReceiveDeliveryHeader>
          .....
      </ReceiveDeliveryHeader>
      <ReceiveDeliveryItem>
            ....
      </ReceiveDeliveryItem>
      <ReceiveDeliveryItem>
            ....
      </ReceiveDeliveryItem>
      <ReceiveDeliveryHeader>
          .....
      </ReceiveDeliveryHeader>
      <ReceiveDeliveryItem>
            ....
      </ReceiveDeliveryItem>
 </ReceiveDelivery>
</DataArea>
```

And the desired output is

```
<DataArea>
      <ReceiveDelivery>
          <ReceiveDeliveryHeader>
              .....
          </ReceiveDeliveryHeader>
          <ReceiveDeliveryItem>
                ....
          </ReceiveDeliveryItem>
          <ReceiveDeliveryItem>
                ....
          </ReceiveDeliveryItem>
       </ReceiveDelivery>
       <ReceiveDelivery>
          <ReceiveDeliveryHeader>
              .....
          </ReceiveDeliveryHeader>
          <ReceiveDeliveryItem>
                ....
          </ReceiveDeliveryItem>
       </ReceiveDelivery>
     </DataArea>
```

There can be 1 or more items that follow a header. I want the ReceiveDelivery parent node to be duplicated for every header and the items that only follow that header. Please help.

Thanks Martin for your inputs.
I'm using XSLT 2.0. Here is my code

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >

    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ReceiveDelivery">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="ReceiveDeliveryHeader">
      <ReceiveDelivery>         
              <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>           
         </ReceiveDelivery>    
      </xsl:for-each-group> 
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Is this how it should be? But the output is the same as input. Could you please help?

Comment: Can you say whether you can use XSLT 2.0 or above? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2 or 3 it is a simple grouping problem using `for-each-group group-starting-with`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="ReceiveDelivery">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="ReceiveDeliveryHeader">
          <xsl:copy select="..">
              <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
          </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTA2

Sample is XSLT 3 but the grouping works the same for XSLT 2, only you would need to spell out the `xsl:mode` as the identity transformation template and use an explicit literal result element `<ReceiveDelivery>` or an `<xsl:element name="{name(..)}">` instead of the `<xsl:copy select="..">`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using XSLT 2.0. I have edited the question with xslt that i wrote. But output is same as input. Could you please check?

Comment: I suspect your "real" XML input sample is different from the one you have shown so far and uses one or more namespaces, please edit your question and show minimal but complete and well-formed samples of the XML you have, the XSLT you use, the result you get and the result you want, together with information about the used XSLT processor.

Comment: See http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/94hvTyH for an XSLT 2 example using the input from your question with the grouping I suggested plus the identity transformation template, it for sure groups and wraps the elements as requested.

Comment: And see the adaption http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/94hvTyH/1 with `xpath-default-namespace="http://example.com/foo"` in case your XML input has elements in a namespace.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your adaptation  xsltransform.hikmatu.com/94hvTyH/1 was very useful. My input XML was having elements in a namespace. When I modified my XSLT, i got the desired output.